# Suitescript 2.0 Get Button on a sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have an older Suitescript 1.0 user event script where on the BeforeLoad I change a label on a button in a sublist. (note this is a button on the sublist not on the main header of the form
In order to do that I did something like this:

```
function changePackageContentsButtonLabel(type, form, request) 
    {
      var mySublist = form.getSubList('recmachcustrecord_tst_my_sublist');
      if(mySublist != null)
      {
        var NewButton = mySublist .getButton('newrecrecmachcustrecord_tst_my_sublist');
        if(NewButton != null)
        {
          NewButton .setLabel('New Label Text');
        }
      }
}
```

that worked fine in that i could find the button based on a call to the sublist.getButton

In 2.0 I was wondering how to do that.
I had thought i would call the getButton that is based off the context.form but it does not seem to find the button in that case.    And though there are methods to addButton on a sublist, there does not appear to be a getButton on it.   I know i could use JQuery but that may be a bit more brittle it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to put the logic I wanted into a client script and called it off of the pageInit.    What I had to do was use native javascript and locate the button (by document.ElementById()   and when i got that element I was able to change the value.    This was not the desired way but it seems that 2.0 does not allow you to locate a button on a sublist like 1.0 did.

Comment: NetSuite confirmed to me that to use 2.0 this is the only option.   Otherwise 1.0 can be used to access and modify (remove) buttons on a subtab but they note that is not a documented feature so to use at own awareness of that.

Answer (score 0):

In the Netsuite help section search for

> SuiteScript 1.0 to SuiteScript 2.0 API Map

After you get the button object, use `label` property to get or set a value for the button label.

```
var myButton = form.getButton({
    id : 'buttonid'
});

myButton.label = "New Label Text"
```

Comment: this does not work because the button is on the sublist so that call to getButton come back empty